# Is $\mp a$ actually different than $\pm a$?

Tags: elementary-functions, convention

So, the way I understand $\pm a$ as a general concept is basically as follows: $\pm a$ is really just two numbers, functions, or whatever $a$ represents, but the catch is that one of the $a$'s is positive, and the other is negative.

All of that makes sense to me. Mathematicians like to be efficient, but also precise, so they created a way to represent two (or more) **entirely** different objects, simply by using a special symbol.

These, then, are my questions:

- Is $\pm a$ **actually** different than $\mp a$?
- Why aren't there more these, if you will, Frankenstein symbols?
- If the answer to my previous question is, "*There are*," then why aren't they as common?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On its own, $\mp a$ means the same thing as $\pm a$.

**However** -- and this is a big however -- you almost never see $\mp$ unless it occurs in an expression *with* $\pm$ being used as well. And then it means "the opposite of whatever sign $\pm$ is currently."

For example, the sum-or-difference of cube factorizations can be fit into one formula $$a^3 \pm b^3 = (a \pm b)(a^2 \mp ab + b^2),$$

where it should be understood that the sign in $(a \pm b)$ needs to be different from the sign of $ab$.

I suspect $\pm$ and $\mp$ are atypical because addition and subtraction are such well-behaved mirror-images of each other. More importantly, there are many situations in which you'll "either do one, or the other."

I can't really think of any pair of operations that work like that, to they point that we'd 'Frankenstein' their symbols together. That doesn't mean there *aren't* any, but even multiplication and division don't tend to crop up like that, and they'd be obvious second candidates. (Although we could write "either $ab$ or $\frac{a}{b}$" as $ab^{\pm 1}$ if we wanted to, and still not need a comparable hybrid symbol).

Comment: You're the only one who answered the whole question, and you gave a good answer. :) Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help! The last two parts are harder to answer, I would be happy to be proven wrong there :)

Answer (score 4):

$\pm a$ and $\mp a$ represent the same thing.
However consider expressions:

$x \pm y \pm z$

and:

$x \pm y \mp z$

First one stands for either $x+y+z$ or $x-y-z$ while the second stands for $x+y-z$ or $x-y+z$. That's why we have two symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Standing by themselves $\pm a$ and $\mp a$ mean the same thing; usually the set $\{ a, -a \}$, such as solutions to some equation.

The notation $\mp a$ is a handy abbreviation in certain contexts. For instance
$$b_\pm = c \mp d$$
means $b_+ = c -d$ and $b_- = c + d$.

Comment: You're too fast for me!  +1  I was just writing something very similar to this.

Comment: Or, in my experience more often: $\pm a \mp b$ meaning $a-b$ or $-a+b$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are functions of the form $a\pm b\mp c$.
Which is the two functions $a-b+c$ and $a+b-c$.